# Поиск подстроки при помощи регулярного выражения и метода search

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

```
/**
 * Test
 */
'./path';

/**
 * Lib
 */
'./lib/';
```

Вверху показан код, который я преобразую в строку и пытаюсь найти совпадение методом search.
Регулярное выражение звучит, как "найти комментарии, после которых идет строка **'./lib/';**  .
Вот как я ищу -

```
var data = '\n/**\n * Test\n */\n\'./path\';\n\n/**\n * Lib\n */\n\'./lib/\';';
var re = new RegExp('\\n\\/\\*\\*\\n' + '([\\s\\S]+?)' + ' \\*\\/\\n' + "'./lib/");
console.log( data.search( re ) );
```

И вот этот код в действии http://jsfiddle.net/paj422ea/
И вот я не пойму, почему вхождение 0?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем искать искать что-то типа `Test`, если в условии нужна только строка **'./lib/';**?
Вот как-то так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var comment = /\/\*\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*\/\s*'\.\/lib\/';/.exec(document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML);
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = comment[1];
});
```

```html
<pre>
/**
Не то
*/
'../path/';

Бред всякий

/**
 Опять не то

*/
'myVar';

/**
Нужный комментарий!
*/
'./lib/';

Опять не нужное
</pre><hr />
<div id='result'></div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLb9mj80/

Comment: Включайте код прямо в ответ, ссылки на jsfiddle могут служить только дополнением. И вообще, уже работают фрагменты кода (Ctrl+M), пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '\n/**\n * Test\n */\n\'./path\';\n\n/**\n * Lib\n */\n\'./lib/\';';
str.search(/(\/\*)([^\*]|\*[^\/])*?(\*\/)\n'\.\/lib\/'/g); // 28
```